# Comparing the time in the time-distance problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

> Two trains start at point A and B and travel towards each other at a speed of $50$km/hr and $60$Km/hr respectively. At the time of meeting the second train has traveled $120$ km more than the first train. Now the distance between them is:

Now I did manage to solve it with a little help and its like this:

First Train starting from $A$:

$t = x/50$

Second Train starting from $B$:

$t = (120+x) / 60$

Comparing $A$ and $B$ we get $x$ and then using the value of $x$ we can calculate the total distance between them which is $1320$.

My question is why are we comparing $A$ and $B$. The only reason we would compare them is if they were equal. I don't understand how time could be equal when the two trains meet. I would appreciate it if someone could kindly clarify this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important that both the trains start at the same time instant. Hence, when they meet, both trains would have taken the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As in each hour 2nd train will travel (60 -50 = 10 km) more than 1st train.
so the given difference in distance is 120 so time taken = 120/10 = 12 hour 
so the distance b/t places = 12*(50+60) = 1320 km

for more such concepts : https://www.handakafunda.com/motion-of-two-bodies-in-a-straight-line/